# Android Google maps navigation view overlay button

Tags: android, google-maps

How to implement a button on navigation view google maps android which when clicked opens a different app?

Such a button can be seen in google maps navigation view of Ola and Uber driver apps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can tie up with google seems uber and ola have check this link https://developers.google.com/maps/

Comment: Can't seem to find a solution in the link you provided.